# How to get svg icons as Single Svg

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg

```js
const star = () => (
    <>
        {Array(5)
            .fill("")
            .map((_, i: any) => (
                <svg
                    key={i}
                    fill="gray"
                    height="1em"
                    width="1em"
                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                >
                    <path d="M3.612 15.443c-.386.198-.824-.149-.746-.592l.83-4.73L.173 6.765c-.329-.314-.158-.888.283-.95l4.898-.696L7.538.792c.197-.39.73-.39.927 0l2.184 4.327 4.898.696c.441.062.612.636.283.95l-3.523 3.356.83 4.73c.078.443-.36.79-.746.592L8 13.187l-4.389 2.256z" />
                </svg>
            ))}
    </>
);
```

This is my function to get 5 star SVGs, in here this is rendered as 5 separate SVG icons. How can I make this rendered as one SVG. The star count may change from time to time. Simply I want to get all looped star as a single SVG, **not wrapped as an SVG**.

Comment: Your `key` is set on the svg element, so you’d need to move that to the repeating element. The `path` element seems to be the obvious thing to repeat, but I have ne idea what the difference between “as a single svg” and “wrapped as a svg” is.

Answer (score 0):

This is interesting, normally we want to have svg to sit in one place.

But i think what you asked can be done, because you can just define a component with the star for pieces of svg.

```
  const Star = () => <g><path d=""></g>
```

And then define the voting component as you normally do

```
  const StarsIcon = () => (
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <Star />
      <Star />
      <Star />
      <Star />
      <Star />
    </svg>
  )
```

So it can be done.

###### Note:

But this isn't recommended for further customization. How about to light up one star later if user hovers on one?

Basically if you go with your approach then all the logic needs to be built in the `StarsIcon`, comparing to used to be, we can code individual logic in a single `Star`. Just from the cost point of view.

Comment: Thank you for your clear answer this seems to be work ,:)

Comment: Please vote up the answer if that works for you, thanks man.